# Sequelize find. how to include constant value attributes in a find query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

¿How can I retrieve all attributes from a table, plus a new column/attribute with a constant value for every row?
As I saw on the docs, it shuld be something similar to this:

```
my_model.findAll({
    attributes:{
        include:[['constant_value','new_attribute_name']]
    }
}).then(...);
```

Any clue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes object is to specifically select attributes that are already on the model.

From what I can gather you can't add attributes to models but you can however add methods to the model.

See the documentation for those methods [here](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#expansion-of-models)

For example you could create a simple class/instance method that simply returns the constant.

You could also create a [hook](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/hooks/) that adds the constant to the model after it has been retrieved.

Comment: How should I add this new attribute inside the Hook? I'm doing somethig like *my_model_instance.dataValues.new_attr = attr_value*. Is this propertly done?

Comment: The model gets passed in as an argument to the hook. So if we use the top example from the hook documentation where it has a model called user. You would simply type user.yourConstant = constantValue or user.dataValues.yourConstant = constantvalue. You'll probably have to experiment with it a bit.

Comment: Actually the second example is the one that works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use literal function in sequelize.

```
my_model.findAll({
    attributes:{
        include: [[Sequelize.literal(`"constant_value"`,'new_attribute_name']]
    }
}).then(...);
```

I just see this question was posted a long time ago but I hope this will be helpful for the others. Thanks

Comment: Small error - Should be a close bracket after the constant and before the comma: Sequelize.literal(\`"constant_value"\`)